# How to use Firestore Security Rules perfectly

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I read the documentation and watched the video about this
but still not understanding perfectly

I mean I know how to write those security rules
but when should I use this?
do I have to write out all Security Rules for all the collections and documents? (if do so, it`s gonna be huge)

for instance, I`m making random dating app right now.
in my situation, I think I would not be so concerned about security unless I'm concerned with the payment system.
If I do not set up security rules for all documents, are all those documents in danger? (unsecured ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want anyone on the internet to be able to read and write any document in your database, you will need to use security rules to protect them.  Whether or not this is going to be a problem for you, it's impossible to tell.  But the possibility exists.

Comment: No, they can view, change, and delete the contents of the documents if your rules don't restrict who can read and write them.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this step by step then you will know how to use rules [this](https://www.fullstackfirebase.com/cloud-firestore/security-rules)

Basic Rules

Our Firestore security rules for Fogo, our image-sharing app, are as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /uploads/{document=**} {
      allow write: if request.auth.token.admin == true ;
      allow read;
    }
​
    match /users/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.admin == true ;
    }
  }
}
```

Let's break these rules down line-by-line.

`service cloud.firestore —` defines the service, in this case it's `cloud.firestore`

`match /databases/{database}/documents —` defines the database; the {database} clause indicates that these rules apply to all Firestore databases on the project

`match /uploads/{document=**} —` creates a new rules block to apply to the uploads collection and all documents contained therein

`allow write: if requests.auth.token.admin == true ;` — allows write access for authenticated sessions with an admin attribute equal to true on the auth token, which is also known as the user's JWT

`allow read;` — allows public read access

`match /users/{document=**}` - creates a new rules block for the users collection and all documents contained therein

allow read, write: if request.auth.token.admin == true ; - allows both read and write access for authenticated sessions with an admin attribute equal to true on the auth token, which is also known as the user's JWT

Comment: I mean I think I may already know this. I want to know more like "area things"

Comment: area thins means